# Problem in C , algorithim not setting up with my mind any advice

Tags: c, algorithm

I need an algorithm or a solution for this problem:

> Please implement in recursion
>
> It is said that a division of an array
> is almost balanced if the numbers in the array can be divided into two
> groups when:
>
> 1. The sum of the numbers in both groups is equal
> 2. One of the groups has at most two members more than the other group
>
> `void almost_balanced_partition(int arr[] , int size)` this Function
> signature

The Problem is  they want me to solve this problem using recursion and I can't use loops!
And I can use only one help function but it must be recursion.
Also they need me to print the two new arrays if they are existed like that:

The original array: `{1,0,1,0}`

The output is:

```
{1,0,0}
{1}
```

Also this recursion so I cannot know what to do the helper function to print or to sum the elements and also how to print it this way without prin help function.
I can't change the function signature or to add more variables to it.

Comment: if i can get help before 23:30 it is preferred and thank you ;)

Comment: Start by doing this _without_ recursion. Get that function working. Without the use of some globals, I'm skeptical that this can be done with recursion. Also, what are the sample input arrays you're using/testing with? Also, note that because the length of each group must be within two of each other, the left size is within `size/2 - 2` to `size/2 + 2`, so you only need to test near the middle of the array if you have two sums (e.g.) `sumleft` and `sumright`.

Comment: re: "I can't change the function signature..." There's no need. The given prototype is for you to fill with the 'set-up' code (defining variables, etc.). Within that function, your code makes the 'top-level' call to the (unwritten) recursive function, passing into it all that it needs to perform the task...

Comment: Do you only need to find **one** possible partition?

Comment: @trincot yes enough one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the partial output strings as arguments to the recursive function, including the sum & count they both represent. When the sum of the two counts is the size of the array then check whether the solution fits the requirements. If so, print it and return 1 as an indication of success. The recursive call should return success too when it gets a success back.

Each recursive call deals with a specific entry of the array, and either adds it to a first partition or to a second partition, making two recursive calls.

For instance:

```
int recur(int arr[], int size, int count1, int count2, int sum1, int sum2, char out1[], char out2[]) {
    int i = count1 + count2;
    if (i == size) {
        if (sum1 == sum2 && abs(count1 - count2) <= 2) {
            if (out1[0]) out1[strlen(out1)-1] = '\0';
            if (out2[0]) out2[strlen(out2)-1] = '\0';
            printf("{%s}\n{%s}\n", out1, out2);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if (count1 * 2 > size + 2 || count2 * 2 > size + 2) return 0;
    int len = strlen(out1);
    snprintf(out1 + len, 10, "%d,", arr[i]);
    int ok = recur(arr, size, count1 + 1, count2, sum1 + arr[i], sum2, out1, out2);
    if (ok) return 1;
    out1[len] = '\0';
    len = strlen(out2);
    snprintf(out2 + len, 10, "%d,", arr[i]);    
    ok = recur(arr, size, count1, count2 + 1, sum1, sum2 + arr[i], out1, out2);
    out2[len] = '\0';
    return ok;
}

void almost_balanced_partition(int arr[], int size) {
    char out1[1000] = "";
    char out2[1000] = "";
    recur(arr, size, 0, 0, 0, 0, out1, out2);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {8, 3, 5, 4, 7, 1, 2}; // Sample input
    almost_balanced_partition(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));    
}
```